# Upload thumbnail to Youtube API using curl

Tags: curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using curl with YouTube API v3 to create a broadcast, modify video title, etc without any issues.  My problem is when I try to add a thumbnail to a video using [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set) from Google.

Here is my sample with the keys changed for security reasons:

```
curl --request POST -v \
  "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set\
?videoId=RoZypUhZY04\
&uploadType=media\
&key=mykey" \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer my_access_token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg'\
  -F 'file=@/Users/adviner/Projects/Prototypes/VendorAPI/source/YouTube/YouTube-BOS.jpg'\
  -F 'filename=YouTube-BOS.jpg'
```

I have tried:

```
-F 'image=@/Users/adviner/Projects/Prototypes/VendorAPI/source/YouTube/YouTube-BOS.jpg'\
```

In the documentation it says to use the following URL to POST the image:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set
```

but when you view the sample it says to use:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set
```

I have tried both and it seems that the images are properly uploaded but I get the following errors:

For the first URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Media type 'image/jpeg; boundary=------------------------136ebfc0c8146cb8' is not supported. ",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Media type 'image/jpeg; boundary=------------------------136ebfc0c8146cb8' is not supported. ",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

When using the URL: https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request does not include the image content.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request does not include the image content.",
        "domain": "youtube.thumbnail",
        "reason": "mediaBodyRequired",
        "location": "body",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the URL that's on [the spec document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set#http-request):

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set`.

In my experience, the sample code page is not one hundred percent reliable (for example, the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint suffers from the same issue).

You'll have to issue the following `curl` call:

```bash
curl --request POST -v \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set\
?videoId=RoZypUhZY04\
&uploadType=media" \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer my_access_token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg'\
  --data-binary '@/Users/adviner/Projects/Prototypes/VendorAPI/source/YouTube/YouTube-BOS.jpg'
```

Notice that instead of the two `-F` options (*form* options), the call above uses one `--data-binary` option, with its argument starting with `@` to indicate that the rest of the argument is a file name.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I modified my script and it's working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

with postman http request :

[POST] [https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId={videoID}&uploadType=media](https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=%7BvideoID%7D&uploadType=media)

```
--headers:  Content-Type: image/jpeg
           Authorization: Bearer ....
```

send file as binary

[image]